# Long waiting when running training model with ML

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, tf.keras

I have trouble for long waiting when I run my training model with Machine Learning using CNNs. Maybe this because my pc has such a bad specs for machine learning.
I have 50000 images for my X_training and must wait up to 1 hours more until it's done.
I think maybe that someone can solve my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe try using kaggle cloud computing for training, it is free.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But maybe are they any option for me to still use my jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, kaggle supports jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Google Collab**. It’s free to use. You can access it withing Google Drive and make sure to change the runtime to GPU. In cases such as CNN, using GPUs can make your training process a lot faster.

Also, I don’t know how you are handling images, but if using TensorFlow/Keras I would also recommend you to use the **ImageDataGenerator** for not loading all images into memory at once, but loading the images needed within each batch. It can save some resources for the computer